# make focusable element unfocusable on webkit

Tags: html, webkit

When a node has a tabIndex setting (other than -1), clicking it will give it focus.   Removing the tabIndex setting should stop that behavior, so that clicking has no effect.

However, on webkit, once a node has a tabIndex, even after tabIndex is removed, the node can still be clicked and focused.   Setting tabIndex=-1 also has the same click problem.

Anyone know a workaround to this problem?

```
<div id="one">one (no initial tabindex)</div>
<div id="two" tabindex=0>two (initially tabindex=0)</div>
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('one').setAttribute('tabindex', 0)">set tabindex on first div</button>
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('one').removeAttribute('tabindex', 0)">remove tabindex on first div</button>
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('two').removeAttribute('tabindex', 0)">remove tabindex on second div</button>
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('one').setAttribute('tabindex', -1)">set tabindex=1 on first div</button>
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('two').setAttribute('tabindex', -1)">set tabindex=1 on second div</button>
```

Comment: Just stumbled onto this issue myself... damned annoying, it is.

Comment: What version of Safari / WebKit?

Comment: Just tried on Chrome 8.0.552.231 and it still occurred.  Not sure what version of webkit I tested on initially.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the second parameter from removeAttribute. You get something like this:

```
<div id="one">one (no initial tabindex)</div> 
<div id="two" tabindex=0>two (initially tabindex=0)</div> 
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('one').setAttribute('tabindex', 0)">set tabindex on first div</button> 
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('one').removeAttribute('tabindex')">remove tabindex on first div</button> 
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('two').removeAttribute('tabindex')">remove tabindex on second div</button> 
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('one').setAttribute('tabindex', -1)">set tabindex=1 on first div</button> 
<button type=button onclick="document.getElementById('two').setAttribute('tabindex', -1)">set tabindex=1 on second div</button>
```

Let me know how is working for you.

Comment: Nope, same problem as before (tested on chrome 10).